# special character to string

Tags: python, string

Regex is new to me. Is it possible to add ' in front and end of a word which is in a string?

I have multiple strings `(eg: str1 = "abc +xyz")`. To this is I want to add ' to a word which is present inside a string (for above eg: `str1 = "abc+xyz"` has to be converted to `str1 = "'abc' +'xyz'"`).

```
input:
str1 = "(abc +xyz)"
str2 = "rc+op"
str3 = "(er+ut)*yu"
```

Expected output:

```
str1 = "('abc' +'xyz')"
str2 = "'rc'+'op'"
str3 = "('er'+'ut')*'yu'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])"
print(re.sub(regex, '"\g<0>"', "(df[er]+df[ut])*df[yu]"))
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\[)` This matches a `[` using Negative lookbehind
- `[^]]+` This matches anything until `]`
- `(?=\])` This matches a `]` using Positive lookahead

Comment: Does this work if  string is like this "(er+ut)*yu" (after conversion "('er'+'ut')*'yu'")

Comment: @CharanNair It will only work for variables enclosed inside `[` and `]`. In your post, you've only included samples using `[` and `]`.

Comment: Ohh! got it, yes but wanted to check if it also works "('er'+'ut')*'yu'" , " 'er'+'ut' "

Comment: is there any pattern which does that?

Comment: probably yes. update your post with proper details to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Oh okay, Yes I have edited it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66658457/how-to-add-or-to-a-word-which-is-in-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
strings = ["df[abc] +df[xyz]", "(df[rc]+df[op]", "(df[er]+df[ut])*df[yu]"]
print("\n".join(s.replace("[", "['").replace("]", "']") for s in strings))
```

Output:

```
df['abc'] +df['xyz']
(df['rc']+df['op']
(df['er']+df['ut'])*df['yu']
```

And if you want to do this with regex, here's one way of doing it:

```
import re

strings = ["df[abc] +df[xyz]", "(df[rc]+df[op]", "(df[er]+df[ut])*df[yu]"]

pattern = re.compile(r"\[(.*?)\]")
print("\n".join(pattern.sub(r"['\1']", s) for s in strings))
```